# Capture Google Adwords Keywords using PHP

Tags: php, google-ads-api

Is there a way to capture google adwords keyword campaign used to a website?
Thanks for your kind response.

Comment: I did something similar before, by `explode()`'ing the `__utmz` cookie. You could use something like [**this**](http://daleconboy.com/portfolio/code/google-utmz-cookie-parser) but [**Google supplies `Not Provided` instead of keyword**](http://www.searchenginejournal.com/google-protect-paid-search-keyword-data-making-provided/99277/)

Answer (score 0):

[Google took the keyword information away](http://googleadsdeveloper.blogspot.ca/2014/04/security-enhancements-for-search-users.html) from the request to protect searcher's privacy.

As an advertiser you can still get the keywords that led to your ads getting clicked from directly in AdWords or via Google's web master tools, but you cant get it in the request itself (e.g. it is not in the referrer any more).

If you want to do this programmatically then I believe you can extract it using the AdWords API.

Hope that helps.